# Grails Database Migration Plugin error onStart

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, database-migration, liquibase

I use Grails 2.3.5, GGTS 3.5.0 and database migration plugin 1.3.8.

I set updateOnStart = true in Config.groovy.

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
```

When my application runs first time (with empty database) it starts perfectly.
But when I stop and start application I get following error:

*Similar errors occur when I run dbm-update or dbm-status after changelog applied.(after tables are created)

```
DEBUG databasemigration.GrailsChangeLogParser parsing changelog.groovy
 INFO  liquibase Reading from databasechangelog
 DEBUG liquibase Executing QUERY database command: SELECT FILENAME,AUTHOR,ID,MD5SUM,DATEEXECUTED,ORDEREXECUTED,TAG,EXECTYPE FROM databasechangelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
 ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.getRanChangeSetList(AbstractDatabase.java:923)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:132)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:625)
    at liquibase.Liquibase$listUnrunChangeSets.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner$_autoRun_closure1.doCall(MigrationRunner.groovy:67)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner$_autoRun_closure1.doCall(MigrationRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:132)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils$executeInSession$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner.autoRun(MigrationRunner.groovy:56)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationRunner$autoRun.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin$_closure2.call(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:177)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.performPostProcessing(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:177)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

UPDATE:

I decompiled and found the error line in Liquabse.jar(AbstractDatabase.class):

```
public List<RanChangeSet> getRanChangeSetList()
    throws DatabaseException
  {
    if (this.ranChangeSetList != null) {
      return this.ranChangeSetList;
    }
    String databaseChangeLogTableName = escapeTableName(getLiquibaseSchemaName(), getDatabaseChangeLogTableName());
    this.ranChangeSetList = new ArrayList();
    if (hasDatabaseChangeLogTable())
    {
      LogFactory.getLogger().info("Reading from " + databaseChangeLogTableName);
      SqlStatement select = new SelectFromDatabaseChangeLogStatement(new String[] { "FILENAME", "AUTHOR", "ID", "MD5SUM", "DATEEXECUTED", "ORDEREXECUTED", "TAG", "EXECTYPE" }).setOrderBy(new String[] { "DATEEXECUTED ASC", "ORDEREXECUTED ASC" });
      List<Map> results = ExecutorService.getInstance().getExecutor(this).queryForList(select);
      for (Map rs : results)
      {
        ***String fileName = rs.get("FILENAME").toString();***
```

Comment: Could you tell the grails version and IDE which you are using?

Comment: Grails 2.3.5 and GGTS 3.5.0

Comment: Could you try commenting out the "run" in BuildConfig under grails.project.fork and see if that works.

Comment: it is already set to false "grails.project.fork.run=false"